# Correctly subset R variable with greater than condition

Tags: r

I want to plot a scatterplot for all the values of a dataframe column  greater than the number 28.

This works fine to return the results:

```
abovezero <- clicks > 28
```

But the scatterplot inexplicably renders the values as integers of just 1 or 0. How do I convert the variable in order to plot the actual values?

Comment: Perhaps `clicks[clicks > 28]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aboveZero <- clicks[clicks>28]
```